# Button click event is not firing on the second click for the user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Hi all I have created a user control where I will have some 3 buttons on each and every button click I will assign a grid dynamically based on the button click with few values. Every thing works fine but when I delete a row from gridview and performing button click eventn again it is not firing the button click event

My code in `User control`

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
  {
     dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("xx", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("xx", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("xx", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("xx", typeof(string));
  }
   }

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
  {
  }
  else
  {
      addrow("Some", txt1.Text);
  } 
}

protected void grd_Deleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
       int iIndex;
        iIndex = grd.FocusedRowIndex;
        dt.Rows[iIndex].Delete();
        grd.DataSource = dt;
        grd.DataBind();
}
```

What to do to perform the button click operation to fire again after deleting a row

Comment: Debug and check is ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt (or) null second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with in the `grd_Deleting`

I don't see where are you setting the new values (after deletion)  in the `view-state`.

```
protected void grd_Deleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
   int iIndex;
    iIndex = grd.FocusedRowIndex;
    dt.Rows[iIndex].Delete();
    //set dt to view state
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] =dt;
    grd.DataSource = dt;
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi Shekhar even if I assign `ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;` after `grd.DataBind();` I am unable to fire the button

Comment: You code is bit difficult to under stand. As far my understanding you are binding the gridview from `ViewState`. So after deleting the row you should update the view state also. So that you get the right values in the grid.

Comment: Yeah shekhar I rectified now

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after delete

```
ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt // OR Null base on your requirement
btn1_Click(null, null);
```

And one more thing The RowDeleting event occurs when an end-user has clicked the Delete command or the DeleteRow method has been called. To cancel the delete operation, set the event parameter's Cancel property to true.

```
e.cancel=true; //in finally
```

see [reference](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletingtopic)

Comment: may i know what you wanted to do in delete exactly could you explain brefly

Comment: I would like to delete a row and rebind the grid which working perfectly but later on I am unable to perform any operation either button click or even the delete option in gridview

Comment: Did you use dt.AcceptChanges(); after delete